# HTML5 Boilerplate with blueprint css

Tags: css, html, blueprint-css, html5boilerplate

I'm thinking of combining these two technologies for a new project.

Is this bad idea? Are there any recommended alternative grid systems to use with html5 boilerplate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, [I mixed them both and they worked well together](http://shikiryu.com/html5).

All I had to do is modifying `<div id="container">` with `<div class="container" id="container">`

Answer (score 10):

You can try [Code Kick Off](http://codekickoff.com/), you can combine Boilerplate with any of these grids:

- Less Framework
- Tiny Fluid Grid
- 960.gs
- Blueprint

Comment: it contains scripts outdated, jQuery 1.4.2, modernizr 1.6, if you select blueprint framework it does not append it... plenty of bugs, but nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late replying here, but you could look at [BlueTrip](http://bluetrip.org/) which is Blueprint on steroids

Answer (score 0):

Google for Zurb's Foundation CSS platform: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Has the best of both worlds. Mobile-ready, grids, html5 reset and uses latest scripts and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother integrating multiple solution to create one and get into the overload of integration, learning and implementation. Most of the times its much wiser to choose one product that looks close to sufficing you requirements and use it for complete implementation.  For example have a look at Twitter's Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html and you might not need a grid system.